# String seemingly disappears in C using structs

Tags: c, string, struct

I'm writing a program for an assignment in a C beginner's course. I'm using structs. Here's the code (it's originally longer but here is where the error occurs):

```
typedef struct
{
     int hours, minutes, seconds;
}time;

typedef struct
{
     int id;
     short cat, gender;
     char name[SIZE]; //SIZE is defined with 64
     time times[3];
}runner;

int main(){
    int n, i, j;

/*User types the value of n*/

    runner runners[n];
//Data entry
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("\n\tRunner no. %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Type your name: ");

        while((getchar()) != '\n'); //Buffer flush
        scanf("%64[^\n]", runners[i].name); //I make sure the user can't overflow the array.

        printf("Type your runner id: ");
        scanf("%d", &runners[i].id);

        printf("Type your category (1-. Amateur 2-. Professional): ");
//Here the string seemingly disappears
        do
        {
            scanf("%d", &runners[i].cat);

            if(!(runners[i].cat == 1) && !(runners[i].cat == 2))
                printf("Incorrect data. Try again: ");
        }while(!(runners[i].cat == 1) && !(runners[i].cat == 2));

        printf("Type your gender (1-. Male 2-. Female): ");

        do
        {
            scanf("%d", &runners[i].gender);

            if(!(runners[i].gender == 1) && !(runners[i].gender == 2))
                printf("The typed value is incorrect. Try again: ");
        }while(!(runners[i].gender == 1) && !(runners[i].gender == 2));

        printf("Type your records: \n");

        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            printf("\n\tRecord %d\n", j + 1);

            printf("Hours: ");
            scanf("%d", &runnerss[i].times[j].hours);

            printf("Minutes: ");

            do
            {
                scanf("%d", &runners[i].times[j].minutes);

                if(runners[i].times[j].minutes > 59 || runners[i].times[j].minutes < 0)
                    printf("The typed value is incorrect. Try again: ");
            }while(runners[i].times[j].minutes > 59 || runners[i].times[j].minutes < 0);

            printf("Seconds: ");

            do
            {
                scanf("%d", &runners[i].times[j].seconds);

                if(runners[i].times[j].seconds > 59 || runners[i].times[j].seconds < 0)
                    printf("The typed value is incorrect. Try again: ");
            }while(runners[i].times[j].seconds > 59 || runners[i].times[j].seconds < 0);
        }
    }
//End of data entry

//Let's print the data
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        char c[14], s[8];

        switch(runners[i].cat)
        {
            case 1:
                strcpy(c, "Amateur");
            break;

            case 2:
                strcpy(c, "Professional");
            break;
        }

        switch(runners[i].gender)
        {
            case 1:
                strcpy(s, "Male");
            break;

            case 2:
                strcpy(s, "Female");
            break;
        }

        printf("\n\tRunner no. %d\n", i + 1);

        printf("Name: %s\n", runners[i].name); //Nothing gets printed

        printf("Gender: ");
        puts(s);

        printf("Category: ");
        puts(c);

        printf("Id: %d\n", runners[i].id);

        for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            printf("\n\tTime %d\nHours: %d\nMinutes: %d\nSeconds: %d\n", j + 1, runners[i].times[j].hours, runners[i].times[j].minutes,
            runners[i].times[j].seconds);
        }
    }
//End
    return 0;
}

}
```

At the end, I have to print the info but the string disappears. I've debugged and printed the variable value after the scanf and it looks like it's fine, but before (or after, I don't know) the first do while the string gets filled with null characters.
The logic is sound and I really can't see what's going on, probably something is ruining the array. It's pretty weird. Thanks for any help.
If it's of some use I'm currently using Manjaro Linux with GCC 9.3 and glibc 2.31.

Edit: added the rest of the code.

Comment: There is not sufficient amount of information to tell why. The code segment appears to be fine

Comment: This isn't right: `scanf("%d", &runners[i].cat);` because %d means integer but `cat` is a short. Check all your `scanf` format types against the sizes of the variables you're reading into.  Also recommend turning on max warnings, which might point this out.

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code then.

Comment: appears that `scanf()` or something managed to corrupt your string

Comment: @Steve but the string disappeared before this line get executed...

Comment: I believe the maximum field width in scanf doesn't include the terminating null byte, so if you actually enter 64 characters you'll overrun.

Comment: Yeah, I've already corrected that. Now the scanf receives only 63 characters, but the problem persists. It does even with small strings.

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For both the `cat` and `gender` fields, you're using `scanf` format `%d`, which requires a full-sized `int`, so you're corrupting memory in those places.

Comment: Tom and Steve, thanks, that was it. Already posted an answer to mark as solved.

Comment: After `printf("Type your name: ");` (user types name) and you do `while((getchar()) != '\n'); //Buffer flush` -- where do you think the name went? Then you do `scanf("%64[^\n]", runners[i].name);`? Should be `printf("Type your name: "); if (scanf("%64[^\n]", runners[i].name) != 1) { /* handle error */ }; while((getchar()) != '\n'); //Buffer flush`

Comment: Note that if the string is `char name[64];`, you must specify at most 63 in the `scanf("%64[^\n]", runners[i].name);`.  Also note that the loop `while((getchar()) != '\n'); //Buffer flush` doesn't handle EOF; it should be more like: `{ int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ; } //Buffer flush`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I think the 'buffer flush' loop eats the newline after the `scanf()` input that sets the size, `n`.  That isn't shown, though.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm still a beginner but that you describe is a good practice. Where I can learn more about exception handling? Besides de glibc documentation.

Comment: @LuisSebastian -- it's even simpler than that. Just remember you cannot use any input function correctly without ***checking the return*** to validating the operation succeeded or failed. (the same applies to any function that processes data critical to the continued operation of your code). For all standard library functions like `scanf`, the manual (man page) will tell you exactly what you need to know about how a function behaves and what it returns, e.g. [man 3 scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (this man page is long compared to the rest -- there is a lot there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the format specifier. I declared the short variables as int and that stopped the string from disappearing.